# Does installing Mass Effect 3 to the Xbox 360 hard drive prevent disc swapping?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've installed both discs of Mass Effect 3 to my Xbox hard drive, but every time I enter a new mission I am asked to swap discs out.

Does anyone know if installing it to the hard drive is supposed to prevent having to walk across the room before every other mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I have both discs installed to my drive, and I still have to swap the discs.  Installing the game does nothing to prevent this.  It simply reduces the load times somewhat.

Comment: If that's the case, my wife is going to get upset when I reconfigure the living to put the xBox next to the couch.

Comment: @NASlacker Which is more important? Wife or Commander Shepard?

Comment: @RavenDreamer she probably already wonders why I play FemShep.

Comment: God I hope they can patch this... it's really annoying.

Comment: @Zemm, I think this is by design - it's the way the Xbox 360's "DRM" scheme works.

Answer (score -2):

I downloaded the game from the store and I don't need both disc if have the disc go to game store there you can get the download for free please not it does need 10.60gbs of storage to download

Comment: Sorry, but did you buy a digital copy or a physical copy? The asker is using a a physical copy, which would work differently than a physical copy.